# Forms authentication working under IIS6 redirects back to login page after authentication under IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, webforms, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application that was installed on IIS6 and working fine for quite some time. We are attempting to move that application to an IIS7 site, and the forms authentication is not working.

I am NOT using the Microsoft out of the box login control.

I am redirected properly to the login page. When I enter the credentials, the logging indicates that the credentials were correct. The code then redirects to the ReturnUrl query string value as expected. The cookie appears to be correctly created in the browser.

However, when the browser GET's the ReturnUrl, it redirects again to the login page.

web.config entry for the protected page:

```
<location path="HomeScreen.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow roles="trm_members" />
      <allow roles="trm_clients" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

web.config entry for authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPNETAUTH" loginUrl="Account-Registration/Account-Login.aspx" protection="None" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: The cookie was created in browser? You mean, that the response included a set-cookie header, dont you? Check if the GET Request to the return url contains the created cookie. If not, you might want to set the httpCookie domain in web.config (system.web)

Comment: The response included a set-cookie header, yes. But - it also showed up in the cookies collection of Chrome developer tools. In the developer tools, the cookie includes the proper domain.

As best I can tell, the code behind appears to be working - it's doing the same thing it did in IIS6, but IIS7 doesn't seem to recognize that the browser is logged in, even with the cookie.